# No exact matches in call to instance method 'filter' in Vapor

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor

I'm facing an error regarding 'filter' function [Fluent's query API | Vapor].

I read the documentation that´s provided by Vapor for this case and it seems the syntax is fine. Hence I've no idea where the exact issue is located.

- Error screenshot is attached below:

[image: Screenshot Link]

- Here is the code segment for the whole function:

```
        func login(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<String>
        {
            let userToLogin = try
                req.content.decode(UserLogin.self)
            print("user to login \(userToLogin)")
            
            //Get user from DB
            return User.query(on: req.db)
                .filter( \.$email == userToLogin.email)
                .first()
                .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
                .flatMapThrowing { dbUser in 
                    let verified = try dbUser.verify(password: userToLogin.password)
                    print("attempt verify password \(verified)")
                    if verified == false {
                        throw Abort(.unauthorized)
                    }
                    
                    req.auth.login(dbUser)
                    let user = try req.auth.require(User.self)
                    return try user.generateToken(req.application)
                }
        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is not your filter method, the compiler can't find out what you want to return in your flatMapThrowing try with adding `...{ dbUser -> RETURNTYPE in ... }`
Whatever type `try user.generateToken(req.application)` might be. I guess a string ;)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. Also, are you sure the `$` in `\.email` is necessary? What's the type of `email`?

Comment: Please include the definition of UserLogin structure and User model

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with `filter`, but with `==` that needs to be overloaded.

Make sure you have

```
import Fluent
import Vapor
```

in you file.

Comment: I CANNOT thank you enough!! It took me 2 days trying to figure out the issue. I wish you glad tidings 